# Check if current Download is in a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

So I'm working with the `sinlge-download.php` page and I'm trying to check if the specific product is in a specific category.
Here is what I tried but I only get the ELSE result even if the download is a book.

```
if( in_category( 'Books' ) ) {
    echo 'This product is a book';
   } else {
    echo 'This product is not a book';
   }
```

Comment: What kind of taxonomy is "Books"?

Comment: Books is the category of the Easy Digital Downloads product. EDD products are custom post type called ‘download’. I would like to check if the download page is in the Books category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to EDD docs, the category is: `download_category` [Easy Digital Download Docs](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1198-download-category-and-tag-templates)

For this... use function `has_term` since `in_category` refers to WordPress `post` type `posts` and not for custom post types like the downloads.

```
if( has_term( 'Books', 'download_category' ) ) {
    echo 'This product is a book';
} else {
    echo 'This product is not a book';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if( has_term( $term = '', $taxonomy = '', $post = null ) ) {
    // do something
}

// $term = Category OR Taxonomy name $taxonomy = Taxonomy Name. OR
// "category" if its default WP category $post = Post ID to check. Leave
// empty to pull this from global query
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/